# MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread. how can i solve this issue i dont know?

Tags: mkmapview

I can also try this

```
 [myView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeSomethingFlashyHappen:)withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

But it not Works For me .

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' initWithCoder:: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.'

Comment: Even i can not develop single mapview . When m try to add mkmapview in viewcontroller app is crash. Anyone help me what to do.?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet how you initialise an instance of the MKMapView. Also share your view initialisation which is not responding to the performSelectorOnMainThread:.

Answer (score 1):

hope you found a solution to your issue. I had the same error message and resolved it like this:`DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: [segue/pushViewController])`

Comment: yeah...  Thanks.